# Copying a selected NSArray of Arrays to an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the following line:

```
[self.keys addObjectsFromArray:[newArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

newArray is an array of arrays.

I want NSMutableArray keys to be the array at the first index of newArray.

what this is returning is zero when I should be getting two.

This is how newArray is built, and appears to look right when i debug it.

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", sSelectedCat];
NSArray *newArray = [[aDictionary allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filterPredicate];
```

When I debug the code and hover over [newArray objectAtIndex:0] it is showing it as an NSCFString where I was hoping that it would be an NSArray.

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newArray` is just a normal array of strings. `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` returns a single array. I think you probably want:

```
self.keys = [newArray mutableCopy];
```

This will make `keys` an NSMutableArray containing your filtered keys.